# Include relative path works strangely

Tags: php, path, include

I have this folder and file structure:

- public_html (folder)

  - index.php (file)
- resources (folder)

  - configs (folder)

    - main_config.php (file)
  - render_template.php (file) - (this file is at the same level as configs folder, inside resources folder)

In index.php I call:

```
require_once("../resources/render_template.php");
```

In render_template.php I call:

```
require_once("configs/main_config.php");
```

Or: (both work)

```
require_once("../resources/configs/main_config.php");
```

My questions:

1. Why does the `require_once("configs/main_config.php")` work? Shouldn't the path now need to be relative to the index.php because the render_template.php file is included in the index.php which means need to add ../resources/ to leave the public_html folder?
2. If the first way is correct, why does `require_once("../resources/configs/main_config.php");` then work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it works is anything but strange. It follows a logical pattern.

1. **Why does the `require_once("configs/main_config.php")` work?**

It works because it doesn't asses the relative path based on where this "parent" file is included. `main_config.php` is included in `render_template.php`. It does not need to know where `render_template.php` might be included.

If it actually depended on where the parent file is included, then you would need to define the relative path differently for files from different folders, which obviously cannot work. It has to be universal so the script could be included wherever it's needed.

It is achieved by first including the files at the "lowest" level. `index.php` includes `render_template.php` which includes `main_config.php`. This means that before `render_template.php` contents are added to `index.php`, `main_config.php` contents will be added to `render_template.php`. So they will ultimately together be added to `index.php` at the place where `require_once("../resources/render_template.php")` is called.

2. **If the first way is correct, why does `require_once("../resources/configs/main_config.php");` then work?**

No reason for it not to work. If you take what we've stated in the first answer (that it is independent of where the "parent" is included), it follows an exact path:

- We are currently inside the `resources` folder, in `render_template.php`.
- We move one level above (`..`) into the "root" folder (that contains both `public_index` and `resources` folders).
- We move back into the `resources` folder. The rest is straightforward.

Comment: This answer is very good, thank you so much. But I have another question, in the main_config.php file (which is in the configs folder) I try to require_once("../paths.php"); the paths file is at the same level as the render_template file (in resources folder), but it throws me a warning: require_once(../paths.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in. So by following the same logic as you explained, it should work because it doesn't look where is the main_config or render_template is, but it doesn't? Changing the path to "../resources/paths.php" makes it work.

Comment: You're making an error there. You only need to `require_once("paths.php");` if they're on the same level. `../` takes you one level *above*, and that file isn't there.

Comment: For some reason "/paths.php" doesn't work either, only "../resources/paths.php".

Comment: Sorry, I corrected it in the above comment. I misplaced the `/`.

Comment: I tried that too but not working :/
Here is the structure:
resources (folder)
 - configs (folder)
   - main_config.php (file)
 - render_template.php (file) - (this file is at the same level as configs folder, inside resources folder)
 - paths.php - (same place as an above file, outside of configs folder)
"../paths", "paths"- doesn't work only "../resources/paths.php" works for some reason. I added the update folder structure in this comment maybe it will help you to help me. thank you for your time.

Comment: For files of the same level, simply the name of the file must work. `paths.php` should be equivalent to `../resources/paths.php` in this case.